# Fill textbox on page with localStorage key value from options page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am making an autofill extension. On the options page, the user enters info such as name & email. Then it is saved to the localStorage. Now, what I would like to do is have the value of one of the keys in the localStorage to be the text inputted in a textbox on a specific page. I assume you do this by using a background page. How would I go about doing this? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You want to retrieve what you saved?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a background page. The easiest way is to use [`chrome.storage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) instead of `localStorage` to save the options. You can then access the information from a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), which is the only way to access and modify the DOM of a web page.

Answer (score -1):

On the page you want to show it

```
   function LoadText(){

   var name = window.localStorage.getItem("name");//name
       var email = window.localStorage.getItem("email");//name

        $('#myname').val(name);
        $('#myemail').val(email);
    }
```

Call the function and it will load

Comment: Is there any way to access local storage from a script that is injected on tabs.onUpdated?

Comment: If the device/platform supports LocalStorage and uses JavaScript, then it is possible.

Comment: @BlackPearl This question is about Chrome extensions, and how to access information associated to the extension from an arbitrary domain.